# How to convert a Hexadecimal string to a Hexadecimal data in Delphi?

Tags: string, delphi, hex

I am using the TComPort library, to send a request to the device I need to send the command in Hexadecimal data like the example below

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComPort1.WriteStr(#$D5#$D5);
end;
```

But that is a hardcoded example.

How can I convert `S` into a valid value for `ComPort1.WriteStr`

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S:String;
begin
  Edit1.Text:='D5 D5';
  ComPort1.WriteStr(Edit1.Text);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't send actual hex strings over the port. That is just a way to encode binary data in source code at compile-time.  `#$D5#$D5` is encoding 2 string characters with numeric values of `213` (depending on [`{$HIGHCHARUNICODE}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/HIGHCHARUNICODE_directive_(Delphi)), which is OFF by default).

`TComPort.WriteStr()` expects actual bytes to send, not hex strings. If you want the user to enter hex strings that you then send as binary data, look at Delphi's [`HexToBin()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.HexToBin) functions for that conversion.

That being said, note that `string` in Delphi 2009+ is 16-bit Unicode, not 8-bit ANSI.  You should use `TComPort.Write()` to send binary data instead of `TComPort.WriteStr()`, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  buf: array[0..1] of Byte;
begin
  buf[0] := $D5;
  buf[1] := $D5;
  ComPort1.Write(buf, 2);
end;
```

However, `TComPort.WriteStr()` will accept a 16-bit Unicode string and transmit it as an 8-bit binary string by simply stripping off the upper 8 bits of each `Char`.  So, if you send a string containing two `Char($D5)` values in it, it will be sent as 2 bytes `$D5 $D5`.

Comment: Hello, sorry for delay, I don't get it very clear yet, I am trying to use  `HexToBin(PWideChar(HexStr),bytes,Length(bytes));` then `ComPort1.Write(bytes,Length(bytes));` but is not converting as expected

Comment: Make sure that the length of `HexStr` is an even multiple of 2, and contains only hex digits (`0..9`, `a..f`, `A..F`), no other characters including spaces. And that `bytes` is preallocated to at least `Length(HexStr) div 2` bytes in size.

Comment: I found a way to achieve what I was looking: `for i:=0 to (Length(Hexstr) div 2 - 1) do a:=a+Chr(Byte(StrToInt('$'+Copy(hexStr, (i * 2) + 1, 2))));`